# Android NDK releasing memory

Tags: java, android, c++, memory, android-ndk

I have basic ndk project:
`NdkTest.java` class and `ndk.cpp` file.Now I have C++ object that should be created once, and destroyed when application is killed or closed.
So my `NdkTest.java` looks like this:

```
NdkTest {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("testLib");
    }
    public static native method1();
    public static native method2();
}
```

`ndk.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <jni.h>

extern "C" {
    void packageName_ClassName_method1(Env *, class);
    void packageName_ClassName_method2(Env *, class);
}

ManagerClass *manager = NULL; //this is actually in .h file but for simplicity of this example I put it here

void packageName_ClassName_method1(Env *env, class clazz) {
    if(manager==NULL) {
        manager = new Manager();
    }
    manager->method1();
}

void packageName_ClassName_method2(Env *env, class clazz) {
    if(manager==NULL) {
        manager = new Manager();
    }        
    manager->method2();
}
```

Now... manager should be created only once and it should be used by all my native methods. This code will compile and work but it will cause memory leaks because manager is never destroyed. Where should it be destroyed?
Of course I can create java methods like `createManager()` and `destroyManager()` but I don't want to do that. Is it even possible?
I tried making Manager object global like this:

```
ManagerClass manager;

void packageName_ClassName_method1(Env *env, class clazz) {    
    manager.method1();
}

void packageName_ClassName_method2(Env *env, class clazz) {    
    manager.method2();
}
```

And it also works but I don't know if it's destructor is ever called. I put log in there but it has never shown.

So my question is: What is the best way to deal with releasing memory in Android native development? Is there any good pattern? If the only way is to create java methods`createManager()` and `destroyManager()` then where should I call destroyManager()? Java finalize() is not guarenteed to be called so where should I put it?

---

I have found great video on this topic:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTC0g14ImPc

About 31min. is the best part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Android model of memory management, there is no guarantee that any destructor will be called. The only guarantee you have by the book is that the `onPause()` method will be called for the foreground activity.

OTOH, the Linux kernel takes care of releasing all resources that had been used by a process that shuts down either gracefully or by force.

Therefore unless your Singleton locks some very special system resource which cannot be reclaimed automatically by the kernel, you should not worry about it's destructor. But if it does (e.g. of it locks the Camera), you need a  bulletproof mechanism to unlock this resource as early as possible, preferably in `onPause()`.

All this discussion does not apply to creation of a Singleton. You may use any of the methods you described above, and chose the one that fits best with your architecture. Only keep in mind the race situations when the app destruction sequence may start while the Manager object is still being created (only likely in a multithreaded scenario).

Comment: So you are saying that I can create it with `new` and leave without `delete` and system will care about releasing memory? My class doesn't use anything related to Android. It's only some algorithms that I wrote in C++ for effciency reason.

Comment: Yes, you can ignore the delete part, but two scenarios to keep in mind: make sure that you never recreate the Manager again (e.g. your app was closed and opened again, but the system decided that the process can be reused), and if you use tools to look for memory leaks, they will complain. They don't care about extreme cases of Android process management, so they will be satisfied with the most naïve `delete`.

Comment: What a weird comment. In C++ you cannot _not_ care about the memory you allocated. You have to dispose of it when you don't need it anymore. So stating that te OP should not care about such things is misguided. Of course, in the context of 'the app gets killed' it does not matter. But then you should still care about resource allocation/deallocation. You cannot say: 'ah yes, our library was supposed to be killed by the OS' or things like that.

Comment: @WernerVanBelle I am sorry. The reality is sometimes painful for purists. You may claim that global variables in general and singleton pattern in particular are bad practice, but the language does allow these, and the runtime environment takes care of destroying these. On Android, the objects created on `JNI_OnLoad()` are, for all practical purposes, equivalent to global variables, in that we may never get a chance to control their destruction. Same applies to Java `finalize()` methods: you shall not rely on all `finalize()` methods being called, or called in some specific order.

Comment: @AlexCohn of course, it might be that that is the way it is in Java. That _does not change the fact that if you write C++, you must take care of your memory_. Letting the operating system clean up your mess is no option. Besides, you can at least clean up the C++ resources in the finalize method of the Java code, otherwise you will leak memory.

Comment: @WernerVanBelle I beg to differ. Global variables exist in C++ by definition, and it's not your task to call their destructors. Enters Android, and the rules are changed again: by contract, the chance that such destructors will ever run, is very low.

Comment: @user458577 Unforunately there is no guarantee finalize is called; the JVM may think that a memory-heavy object is tiny (because the memory was allocated in C++), and so not bother to free it. When wrapping C++ objects using JNI I always add an explicit destroy() method which frees the underlying resources.